# gke default-pools from clusters shows no number of nodes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been having this issue that gcp says that there are "unscheduled pods" in my cluster. It then asks for increasing the node number, but even if I increased at the maximum permitted, the default-pool shows no nodes in this cluster.

After the number of nodes was set to 0, it was set to 5 nodes but the gke cluster won't increase

`kubectl get nodes` are returning "No resources found" and the `kubectl get pods` are also returning pods with "Pending" status

Comment: Even though the instance groups for the cluster exists and they have created nodes

Comment: which version are you running?

Comment: I would like to attempt a reproduction of this behavior. Could you please share the version of your GKE Cluster?

Comment: What does "maximum permitted" mean? Maybe your GCE API is failing. Please go to the Cloud Console UI and see if you have enough CPU quotas etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were the nodes scaled up by the same user as who created the cluster?

We found that the nodes were created but couldn't be assigned to cluster. This was logged:
    All cluster resources were brought up, but the cluster API is reporting that: only 0 nodes out of 5 have registered; cluster may be unhealthy.

In the VM Instance Logs, the following error was logged:
    Supplied fingerprint does not match current metadata fingerprint.